# RecyclearView + Glide + Scroll : Load images taking too long or not loading

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I am using Glide Image Loader.
it takes too long (more than 200 seconds)to load image from server
 and in some cases do not load. 
All images are stored on Cloud server.

When I scroll back to the top the image is displayed like first time and it takes a little time to be displayed ,Image Caching is also not working properly
In Application like Amazon,Facebook one time loaded image is not disappears . I want same technique on my application.

> I am using Staggered Gridview using DynamicheightImageview,For that I am calling AsyncTask on onBindViewHolder

```
   new GetImageTask(singleArtDataitem, vh.imageView, position).execute(singleArtDataitem);
```

**AsyncTask**

```
     private class GetImageTask extends AsyncTask<SingleArtData, Void, Float> {


        private SingleArtData item;
        private final DynamicHeightImageView imageView;
        int position;

        public GetImageTask(SingleArtData item, DynamicHeightImageView holder, int position) {
            this.imageView = holder;
            this.position = position;
        }

        @Override
        protected Float doInBackground(SingleArtData... params) {
            item = params[0];
             try {

                if (GlobalMethods.isNotEmpty(item.getImageName())) {
                    item.setImagefullurl(baseuri + item.getImageName());
                    URL neturl = new URL(item.getImagefullurl());
                    final Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(neturl.openConnection().getInputStream());
                    int width = image.getWidth();
                    int height = image.getHeight();
                    item.setImage_width(width);
                    item.setImage_height(height);
                    float ratio = (float) height / (float) width;
                    item.setImage_ratio(ratio);
                } else {
                    item.setImagefullurl(null);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

                item.setImagefullurl(null);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return item.getImage_ratio();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Float result) {

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();
            rlp.height = (int) (rlp.width * result);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(rlp);
            imageView.setHeightRatio(result);

            if (GlobalMethods.isNotEmpty(item.getImagefullurl())) {
//                Picasso.with(mContext)
//                        .load(baseuri + item.getImageName()).placeholder(PlaceHolderDrawableHelper.getBackgroundDrawable(position))
//                        .error(R.drawable.ic_med)
//                        .into(imageView);
                Glide.with(MyApplication.getInstance())
                        .load(item.getImagefullurl()).placeholder(PlaceHolderDrawableHelper.getBackgroundDrawable(position))
                        .error(R.drawable.loadicon)
                        .placeholder(PlaceHolderDrawableHelper.getBackgroundDrawable(position))
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                        .skipMemoryCache(false)
                        .into(imageView);
            }


        }


    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please add code of  adapter class

Comment: Please add some code also show where glide is attached to the image also can you approximate the image size

Comment: Question edited

Comment: @OmInfowaveDevelopers Adapter class added

Comment: @Xenolion Image size is appropriate of 5mb

Comment: each image is about 5MB ?

Comment: @SushinPv No Image size varies.

Comment: The best thing u can do is decrease the size of images. Because all these images should be downloaded from the server. So it uses a lot of bandwidth.

Comment: If you are using any backend language for the cloud. Instant of sending the actual image just pass the thumbnails of each image. This way you can fast up the process

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156335/discussion-between-rose-and-sushin-pv).